# Issue floating paragraphs left and right on same line in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float, browser-bugs

I'm attempting to float two paragraphs left and right on one line, using the method given here http://css-tricks.com/left-align-and-right-align-text-on-the-same-line/

I'm coming up with an issue where both paragraphs are wrapping over two lines for no apparent reason.

This happens in Chrome, but Firefox displays the paragraphs on one line as intended.

Here's the link to a test case http://jasonbradberry.com/test-case-sophie/

Here's a screenshot of how I see it http://oi39.tinypic.com/2us8mpt.jpg

Could this be a bug or just a browser quirk?

Thanks.

Comment: it looks fine for me on chrome both are on the same line

Comment: Hmmm, strange. Updated Chrome and now it looks fine. Might have been a bug in the previous version!

Comment: Oddly, this issue has now returned, with no changes to the CSS. Here's a screenshot http://oi39.tinypic.com/2us8mpt.jpg – Any ideas?

Comment: It still looks fine to me, maybe you are zoomed out?

Comment: See screenshot link added above.

Comment: It looks like it's a width issue, and the text is going to the next line... I think you're zoomed out in your browser.

Comment: Yes, I had thought it might be a width issue, but my browser is definitely not zoomed in or out. Just reset it and it's still the same!

Comment: All I can see is that when I take the float:left; and float: right; off the two paragraphs, they revert to single line, so it seems the width is related to the floats?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31588/discussion-between-pandavenger-and-jasonbradberry)

Comment: Ok it seems this must be a bug as it appears and reappears intermittently. Anyone else notice the same thing?